# Python - Allow User To Select Conditions Before Plotting

Tags: python, graph, matplotlib

How Can i Allow User to select conditions before plotting?

For eg. select time from 00:15:00 to 01:00:00 
        & select AMB_TEMP then plot a graph using these information

this is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import time, datetime

x = []
y = []
t = []

fig = plt.figure()
rect = fig.patch
rect.set_facecolor('#31312e')

readFile = open('data.txt', 'r')
sepFile = readFile.read().split('\n')
readFile.close()

for idx, plotPair in enumerate(sepFile):
    if idx > 5:
        xAndY = plotPair.split(';')
        time_string = xAndY[0]
        time_string = time_string.replace(' ', '')  # remove blanks
        datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(time_string, '%H:%M:%S')
        t.append(datetime_obj)
        x.append(float(xAndY[2]))
        y.append(float(xAndY[3]))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, axisbg='blue')
ax1.plot(t, y, 'c', linewidth=3.3)

plt.title('Alternate Energy')
plt.xlabel('time mins')

plt.show()
```

- What the code does is just plot from 2 columns, user can't manipulate any of the data

This is my txt file data:

```
[messung]
Uhrzeit;
Intervall;AMB_TEMP;IRAD;W_D;W_S;Poly_M_Tem;TF_M_Temp;
s;DegC;W/m2;Deg;m/s;DegC;DegC
[Start]
00:00:00;900;25.3;55.8;4.5;0.4;;
00:15:00;900;26.1;55.8;5.5;1.0;;
00:30:00;900;26.1;55.8;6.1;1.0;;
00:45:00;900;26.1;55.9;5.7;0.9;;
01:00:00;900;26.1;55.9;5.8;0.7;;
01:15:00;900;26.1;55.8;6.4;0.8;;
01:30:00;900;26.1;55.8;6.1;0.8;;
01:45:00;900;26.1;55.8;5.7;1.0;;
02:00:00;900;26.0;55.8;5.8;1.1;;
.
.
.
22:45:00;900;25.0;55.7;6.1;0.6;;
23:00:00;900;25.0;55.8;5.2;0.4;;
23:15:00;900;25.2;55.8;5.7;0.5;;
23:30:00;900;25.3;55.8;6.2;0.5;;
23:45:00;900;25.4;55.8;5.8;0.4;;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you are looking for is : `raw_input` which allow you to ask a question for example and to get an input from the user ;)

```
s = raw_input('Select a time from 00:15:00 to 01:00:00')
```

Then you have to loop while the input is not between your conditions. And same for the second input you need.

You can see more here : https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input

If you want you can also create a GUI interface to get it more beautiful.

Comment: how can i plot the time if i have a txt data that comes with a date & time. for example, 

23/7/2014 6:00P.M, 17.8
23/7/2014 6:15P.M, 27.8
23/7/2014 6:30P.M, 19.8
23/7/2014 6:45P.M, 12.8

Comment: Just parse it to the format you need if it contains all the informations you need.